Algorithm for Distributing Points within Geometric Shapes
geometric shape example
I have a problem and would like to know the names of algorithms that could solve it.
Suppose I have a geometric shape, such as a .shp file, and a predefined number of points that I want to allocate within this shape, while maintaining a minimum distance from the edge. What would be the most effective way to allocate these points so that they maintain the greatest possible distance from each other, meet the predefined number of points, and respect the minimum distance from the edge? Is there an algorithm that can help me solve this problem, especially considering that the geometric shape could be very irregular?
I tried creating grids along the geometric shape and allocating points in the middle of each grid, but the distribution is not good.
    def _generate_systematic_sample_points(self, shp, plot_area):
        if self.sample_number < 1:
            max_number_of_points = math.ceil((self.sample_number * self.total_area) / plot_area)
        else:
            max_number_of_points = self.sample_number

        grid_number = math.ceil(math.sqrt(max_number_of_points))

        extent = shp.extent()
        x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = extent.xMinimum(), extent.yMinimum(), extent.xMaximum(), extent.yMaximum()

        if not (np.isfinite(x_min) and np.isfinite(y_min) and np.isfinite(x_max) and np.isfinite(y_max)):
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Layer extent contains infinite or NaN values.", 'Your Plugin Name', Qgis.Critical)
            return None

        if x_min >= x_max or y_min >= y_max:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Invalid range of x or y values.", 'Your Plugin Name', Qgis.Critical)
            return None

        side_length = math.sqrt(plot_area)
        x_spacing = (x_max - x_min) / grid_number
        y_spacing = (y_max - y_min) / grid_number

        valid_points = []
        offset = 0

        while len(valid_points) < max_number_of_points and offset < side_length:
            for i in range(grid_number):
                for j in range(grid_number):
                    x = x_min + j * x_spacing + offset
                    y = y_min + i * y_spacing + offset

                    if x > x_max or y > y_max:
                        continue

                    square_centroid = QgsPointXY(x + side_length / 2, y + side_length / 2)

                    point = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(square_centroid)
                    if self._check_point_within_polygons(point, shp) and self._check_points_distance(point, plot_area,
                                                                                                     valid_points):
                        valid_points.append(point)
                        if len(valid_points) >= max_number_of_points:
                            break
                if len(valid_points) >= max_number_of_points:
                    break
            offset += side_length / 2

        if len(valid_points) < max_number_of_points:
            remaining_points = max_number_of_points - len(valid_points)
            attempts = 0
            max_attempts = 3000
            while remaining_points > 0 and attempts < max_attempts:
                x = np.random.uniform(x_min, x_max)
                y = np.random.uniform(y_min, y_max)
                point = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x, y))
                if self._check_point_within_polygons(point, shp) and self._check_points_distance(point, plot_area,
                                                                                                 valid_points):
                    valid_points.append(point)
                    remaining_points -= 1
                attempts += 1

        if len(valid_points) < max_number_of_points:
            QMessageBox.warning(self.dlg, "Warning!",
                                "Unable to generate plots with the established criteria. Only the possible plots were generated.")

        if valid_points:
            point_layer = self.create_point_layer(valid_points, shp.crs())
            return point_layer
        else:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Could not generate plots with the established criteria.", 'Your Plugin Name',
                                     Qgis.Critical)
            return None


Feels like a disc-covering problem or something where poisson distribution may be helpful. As far as minimum distance from the edge, I would imagine the first step would be defining the shape that is the shrunken version of starting shape in which you would perform the point distribution.

I've implemented Poisson-Disc Sampling and it worked. Thank you so much!

The way I found to solve the problem was to distribute as many points as possible in the area, then identify the two closest points, remove these two points, and install a plot in the middle of where these two points were. Repeat this iteratively until the required number of plots is reached.
